# searching liferay contents in liferay CMS using Lucene syntax

Tags: jakarta-ee, lucene, liferay, liferay-6

I wants to get all the contents stored in Liferay cms based on my query ,I know liferay is using Lucene(Query Parser) behind the scene for example if i search title:"admin" in the search bar of document and media portlet it will display all contents with title "admin",but my question is i want this mechanism programmatically .What mechanism should i use to achieve this particular scenario in my custom Liferay portlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BooleanQuery for that.

Detailed example at : [Example](http://liferaytutorial.blogspot.com/2013/08/liferay-boolean-query-for-searching.html)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Kathiriya ,Is liferay document and media portlet is using the same methodology  that you have mentioned above??? and what is searchContext ???

Comment: Yes, same methodology for Document and Media portlet, searchContext is object which holds metadata like groupId, companyId, etc. You can initliaze that object